# Why the Pointcut expression is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, pointcut

If i keep  `@Pointcut("within(org.example.ShoppingCart.*)")` in `AuthenticationAspect.java` then the `authenticate` method is NOT getting invoked BUT when i change to  `@Pointcut("within(org.example..*)")` then it does get invoked.

Doesn't the 2nd PointCut below automatically include the first one?

`@Pointcut("within(org.example.ShoppingCart.*)")`

`@Pointcut("within(org.example..*)")`

i believe both of these should work.

Following is the code :

ShoppingCart.java

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ShoppingCart {
    public void checkout(String status)
    {
        System.out.println("Checkout method called");
    }
}
```

AuthenticationAspect.java

```
package org.example;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthenticationAspect {
    @Pointcut("within(org.example.ShoppingCart.*)")
    public void authenticationPointCut()
    {
    }

    @Before("authenticationPointCut()")
    public void authenticate()
    {
        System.out.println("Authentication is being performed");
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package org.example;


import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfig.class);

        ShoppingCart cart = context.getBean(ShoppingCart.class);
        cart.checkout("CANCELLED");
    }
}
```

BeanConfig.java

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration // Indicates this is a configuration class
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example")   // Indicates where to find the components/beans
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy // Enables the AspectJ features in project
public class BeanConfig {

}
```

i am learning spring aspect and unsure why the pointcut expression is not working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `within` pointcut designator limits matching to join points of certain types, the problem is your pointcut expression is matching types within `ShoppingCart` because of `.*` in the end. If you remove those characters it should work.

```java
@Pointcut("within(org.example.ShoppingCart)")
public void authenticationPointCut(){}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer fully.  Isn't ``within(org.example.ShoppingCart.*)`` same as ``within(org.example.ShoppingCart)``? What do you mean that  ``within(org.example.ShoppingCart.*)`` limits matching to join points of certain types?

Comment: It's not, because with `.*`  you are trying to match methods of **inner classes** of  `ShoppingCart`. On the other hand, with `within(org.example.ShoppingCart)`, you are saying that all methods of that specific class should be matched.

Comment: @Helena is it more clear to you now?